# Bots fork my repositories on GitHub. What are they going to do?

Tags: github

Today I opened my GitHub feed and saw that 2 of my repositories are forked by multiple bots. All accounts are created 19 or 20 hours ago. Has anybody experienced this? And what are they going to do with my projects?

Edit 1:
These bots also fork many other repos from other users

Comment: 1) How do you know these are "bots"?  2) There is no way of knowing what these people / bots are going to do.  3) What does it matter?  4) If you don't want people forking your code, use a private repo.  Or don't put it on Github at all!

Comment: @StephenC I was just wondering if this is a known issue

Comment: I'm not convinced that it is an "issue".  Or even a "phenomon of interest".  It could just be a coincidence.

Comment: Maybe you just need to read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can do whatever they want, generally. If you don’t want that, the projects shouldn’t be public. Other than that, it looks like some API testing stuff but it’s not really useful info outside of satisfying curiosity, as what the forks do is immaterial to you, pretty much. If bots could do something amazing then it would be a plus. As it stands, bots won’t exactly take your projects into new and unexplored directions :) As long as the forks don’t do something blatant like remove copyright attribution or change licensing terms then it’s a “meh, who cares” thing.

Comment: I never heard of this so I was interested if somebody knows what is the purpose of such bots

Comment: My bet: someone learning to use GitHub api or testing a project that will use bots for something but not necessarily with your repository. You can turn on notifications for the forks to see what was pushed to them.